Can we use Density Functional Theory (DFT) to calculate the second and third-order force constants of a slab?
If we aim to compute the surface phonon lifetime of a Cu(111) surface, the second and third-order force constants are essential (to put in Boltzmann transport equation). However, to my knowledge, it seems that no one has performed such calculations before. Theoretically speaking, is it possible to compute the third-order force constant matrix of a slab using DFT?

Consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE.
